# JSON Exception for input jsonStringarray

Tags: android, json, regex, replaceall

Below is my JSON

```
["[0288144111, Please check File Values:==>For input string: "N/A", 20180201]","[4403244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[4246244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[7097244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[9917244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]"]
```

I am using `replaceAll("[\\\\/:*#?<>|=]", "")` . I am still getting `JSONException` due to quotes in "NA". How can I make sure I just replace quotes around NA and not in the whole input string.

**Edit**

**response:**

```
{"tag":"fetchupdDetailStatus","status":true,"uploadDetails":"[\"[0288144111, Please check File Values:==>For input string: \\\"#N\\\/A\\\", 20180201]\",\"[4403244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]\",\"[4246244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]\",\"[7097244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]\",\"[9917244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]\"]"}
```

**Code:**

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
if (jObj != null) {
 System.out.println("RESPONSE1===>" + jObj.getString("uploadDetails"));
 String uploadDetails = jObj.getString("uploadDetails");
 String jsonFormattedString = uploadDetails.replaceAll("\\\\", "").replaceAll("[\\\\/:*#?<>|=]", ""); 
 System.out.println("Formatted String getFurtherDetails ==>"+jsonFormattedString);
 jsonArrayUD = new JSONArray(jsonFormattedString);  //getting org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 58
}
```

**O/P:**

```
RESPONSE1===>["[0288144111, Please check File Values:==>For input string: \"#N\/A\", 20180201]","[4403244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[4246244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[7097244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[9917244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]"]
Formatted String getFurtherDetails ==>["[0288144111, Please check File ValuesFor input string "NA", 20180201]","[4403244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[4246244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[7097244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]","[9917244111, Upload Not Received, 20180201]"]
```

Comment: That is not a valid json.

Comment: @SripadRaj This is a valid jason but due to quotes in data this is becoming invalid.

Comment: Also,   Tried...  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonFormattedString);  but still getting same excepion..pls check edited question

Answer (score -1):

Your problems are surely coming from the fact that the double quotes weren't escaped from the beginning. According to the docs, you should be using [`JSONObject#quote`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

> **quote**
>
> `String quote (String data)`
>
> Encodes data as a JSON string. This applies quotes and any necessary
> character escaping.
>
> **Parameters**
> `data` `String`: the string to encode. Null will be interpreted as an empty string.